# phonegap ajax calls not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova

I have a phonegap 2.9 app that contain a number of ajax calls (using the angular framework).
This application was working correctly when using the Eclispe IDE, however, when I portered it over to Android Studio, all ajax calls have stopped working. I cannot see any error messages in the console either. I have checked my config.xml file and ensured it has access

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to double check your AndroidManifest.xml and make sure it still has <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />. You might also want to try deploying to Android 4.4 and attaching to Chrome's remote debugger to observe network calls (this is new in 4.4 and I haven't tried it yet).  How are you testing this, in a VM or on a device?

Comment: I am running this in the android emulator. Will check the AndroidManfiest, thanks

Comment: Just checked, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a new copy of the existing virtual device using the AVD Manager and that fixed the problem. After a week of struggling with this I am still not sure why it was not working to start with, possibly file corruption.